# Pressing enter in C input programm

Tags: c, input, getchar

I've been trying to teach myself C off the website http://www.cprogramming.com/.
I've come to the code which requires an input number.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int this_is_a_number;
  printf( "Please enter a number: " );
  scanf( "%d", &this_is_a_number );
  printf( "You entered %d", this_is_a_number );
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

However when I run this, and try to enter a number into the prompt, the command window just closes. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: c and c++ are not the same

Comment: ill remove the tag

Comment: Just run the program from a terminal and you don't need to mess around with "keeping a window open"...

Comment: @KerrekSB, while your statement is true, this would just immediately lead to the slightly modified question why `getchar()` is not waiting. Nothing gained there...

Comment: @Gerhardh: I would welcome that as a full win for the site, since such a question would be precise and searchable.

Comment: @KerrekSB ... precise, searchable and still a duplicate of docens nearly identical questions. That's not so much of a win for the site, I would say.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` reads the number, but leaves the newline character you inputted in the input stream.

So `getchar` fetches it immediately instead of waiting for extra input.

You can add another call to `getchar`. It's probably the simplest solution for your simple program.

Answer (score 1):

Use another `getchar();` to consume the newline character left by the `scanf()` call; so that, the second `getchar();` would *hold* the prompt.

```
getchar();
getchar();
...
```

Normally, you wouldn't need this. But if you are running *exe* (typically Windows) and want to *wait* at the end (which appears to be the case here), this trick would do.